# Check if value is x and exists and then mark complete if all exist

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, if-statement, eloquent

I believe I am over thinking this process to the point I have lost myself.

I have courses which employees take. Each lesson is marked completed when the employee finishes the lesson.

I am trying to check if the employee has completed all course lessons and then mark the course as completed if all lessons have completed.

What I have so far.

1. Query for course lessons.
2. Query for completed lesson from employee.

I'm stuck on checking for each course lesson has the completed the lesson and returning a true or false value.

```
public function lessoncomplete(Request $request)
{
    //LessonLog::create(request()->all());

    $user_id = $request->user;
    $lesson_id = $request->lesson;
    $course_id = $request->course;
    $lessonLog = new LessonLog;
    $lessonLog->user_id = $user_id;
    $lessonLog->course_id = $course_id;
    $lessonLog->lesson_id = $lesson_id;
    $lessonLog->save();

    //get course lessons
    $course_lessons = Lesson::where('course_id', $course_id)->get();
```

//get the lessons the user has completed

```
    $user_lessons = LessonLog::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('course_id', $course_id)->get();
```

//check if each of the lessons for the course are complete for the user.

foreach ($course_lesson as $lesson) {
    $completed = false;

```
foreach ($user_lessons as $user_lesson) {
    if ($user_lesson->lesson_id == $lesson->id) {
        $completed = true;
        break;
    }
}

//If $completed is still false, then the user has not completed the course
dd($completed);
```

}

```
    return response()->json(['success' => 1]);
}
```

Comment: `if($completed = True){` this is an assignment, not a comparison. You may do `if($completed){` instead.

Comment: I edited as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to SO. Maybe you could formulate a more accurate question to help us spot your actual need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `LessonLog` will contain all of the completed lessons? If so, you can just loop through the lessons tied to the course and see which ids match in the lesson log. If they all match, then the course is completed.

Example:

```
foreach ($course_lesson as $lesson) {
    $completed = false;

    foreach ($user_lessons as $user_lesson) {
        if ($user_lesson->lesson_id == $lesson->id) {
            $completed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If $completed is still false, then the user has not completed the course
    //Stop iteration
    if (!$completed)
       break;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code and have tinkered with your suggestion a bit and nothing I do brings back the correct result. If any result exists in the users lessons I get a true value returned.

Comment: You are supposed to add logic as needed in the `$course_lesson` loop to check for a false value. I edited my answer to simply break out of the loop if false, otherwise it will continue to run through the loop and could possibly return true on the next iteration.

Comment: In addition, your update shows you are calling `dd($completed);` inside the loop. This will actually stop execution on the very first iteration and print out the `$completed` variable. When debugging loops, it usually helps to push the results into an array and `dd()` the array after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //check if each of the lessons for the course are complete for the user.

  foreach ($course_lessons as $lesson) {
    $completed = false;

    if($user_lessons->isEmpty()){
    $completed= false;
    }
    else{

    foreach ($user_lessons as $user_lesson) {
        if ($user_lesson->lesson_id == $lesson->id) {
            $completed = true;
            break;
        }else{
            $completed= false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    //If $completed is still false, then the user has not completed the course
    $complete = new CourseCompletions;

    $complete->user_id = $user_id;
    $complete->course_id = $course_id;
    $complete->added_by = '99999';

    $complete->save();
}
```

I see where I left out finishing the check if there was no value. I had tried a few ways to complete it. I think I was mistyping.